# Use sed to remove characters in front of matching keywords

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a text that looks like the following.

```
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0.RDZCUAJ DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0.VWZMXQE DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0.GSVZQKE DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0.UIUVAZD DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0.ELBXBGB DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

I need to remove the 8 characters in front of  `DOWNLOAD</DIV>`, it eventually looked like this.

```
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

Is it possible to do this with the sed or awk command?

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach is the following:

```
$ sed 's,.........DOWNLOAD</DIV>, DOWNLOAD</DIV>,g' input.txt
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

That replaces 9 characters in front of `DOWNLOAD</DIV>` and replaces it with  `DOWNLOAD</DIV>`

Comment: +1 I was seconds too late to post the *same* answer :)

Comment: Thank you. It's working!

Answer (score 2):

With a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs (e.g. GNU sed and BSD/OSX sed):

```
sed -E 's:.{8}( DOWNLOAD</DIV>):\1:' file
```

otherwise with any POSIX sed:

```
sed 's:.\{8\}\( DOWNLOAD</DIV>\):\1:' file
```

e.g.

```
$ sed -E 's:.{8}( DOWNLOAD</DIV>):\1:' file
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

```
$ sed 's:.\{8\}\( DOWNLOAD</DIV>\):\1:' file
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sed 's#SOFTWARE \(.*\)\.[A-Z]\{7\} DOWNLOAD#SOFTWARE \1 DOWNLOAD#' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (née Perl6)**

```
~$ raku -pe 's/ <(. ** 8)> <?before " DOWNLOAD</DIV>" $$ >  //;' download.txt
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.1.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.2.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.3.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.4.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>SOFTWARE V1.0.5.0 DOWNLOAD</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
<DIV>...</DIV>
```

The code above uses the `-pe` autoprint flag in conjunction with the `s///` substitution operator. Inside the left-half of the `s///` operator a zero-width lookahead assertion is used to find the  `DOWNLOAD</DIV>` closing tag, and the preceding 8 characters are exactly captured (and deleted) with the `<(. ** 8)>` code.

HTH.

https://raku.org
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes